# Android Notepad Tutorial - Implementing Search feature

Tags: android, search, full-text-search, notepad

I have been learning Android programming from various books and tutorials from roughly 4-5 months now and have a basic idea of most of the things in Android Programming and I recently started with the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/) and now have the final application after Exercise 3.

I want to add the search feature to my app. So that the notes that are stored in the database can be searched i.e. a word given as search query is checked in the body section of all the notes and then only those notes are listed which contain that specific word.

Please can you suggest some modifications in the existing code or suggest what will be needed to implement this search feature?
How can the SQLite query be modified for this?
or should I use indexof() method of Java after storing the body of all the notes in a String Array? and then just displaying those elements of the array using the for loop and if condition with the indexof() method??

Comment: `"Body LIKE ?"` + `new String[] { "word" }` ... but to implement Search feature of Android you have to build your own ContentProvider ...

Comment: @Selvin I know I can't create a ContentProvider but the method you gave above, that is directly to be used as SQLite query? Please can you ellaborate on how I have to implement it in my Notepad App??

Answer (score 1):

You should integrate this with Search Framework of Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: On that page it is mentioned:-
Note: The search framework does not provide APIs to search your data. To perform a search, you need to use APIs appropriate for your data. For example, if your data is stored in an SQLite database, you should use the android.database.sqlite APIs to perform searches. 
 How can the search be performed for SQLite Database?

Comment: This is not helpful, i don't know why it was given a "Vote Up"?